# Can TFS 2012 Power Tools be used with TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I have TFS 2010 installed on the TFS server, and VS 2012 installed on my workstation, and that's working great except we have some check-in policies that rely on TFPT, and I have not yet installed TFPT on my workstation. I'm wondering if I can just install the newer version, or if I'd have to rely on the older version until TFS is upgraded to 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use VS2012 and point it at both TFS2012 (in the cloud) and a TFS2010 instance. I have TFPT for 2012 installed and everything works OK. I'm not an advanced user of TFPT.

Comment: Thanks, with the reassurance of your success, I gave it a try, and it works like a charm, check-in policies and all.